# how to show data label on legend

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i am trying to plot bar plot but there is problem labels are not showing on legend, any one help how can i show legend there
in my figure data label are showing like 1,2 instead of label

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [3,4, 15, 10, 12]
b = [2,13,4,19,1]
c = [12,3,7,8,4]
d = [12, 13,4,7,14]
df = pd.DataFrame([a,b,c,d], columns=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]).transpose()

df.plot(kind = "bar")
plt.legend(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
plt.legend(ncol=4, loc='center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.06))

plt.xticks(rotation=360)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Did you mean `df = pd.DataFrame([a,b,c,d], columns=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])`? i.e. why the `transpose()`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass all the parameters in `plt.legend()` at once. Try it like this:

```
plt.legend(labels=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"], ncol=4, loc='center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.06))
```

instead of supplying labels and other params separately.

And as pointed by  @BigBen in comments, your code would readily give expected result if you do not use `transpose()`